# First-order necessary condition for a local minimizer

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let C be a convex set in Rn, and let f be a differentiable function on an open set containing C .
First-order necessary condition for a local minimizer : If x∗ ∈ C
is a local minimizer of f on C, then the inner product <∇f(x∗), x − x∗> ≥ 0 for all x ∈ C.
I cannot understand the last line of the proof , how does it take the inner product?
[image]

Comment: "Shouldn't $\nabla f(x^*)$ be zero already" No, not if $x^*$ is on the *boundary* of $C$. Even in single variable calculus, we know that if a minimizer occurs at the boundary of an interval then the derivative is typically not zero at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $n=2$, $C=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, $f(x,y)=x+y$. Then $(0,0)$ is a local minmizer of $f$ on $C$, even though $\nabla f$ is non-zero